# How to log TLS version in API-M?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I want to log the version of TLS in azure API-M event hub logs. I tried the `context.Api.Protocol` but it print out as http/https

Answer (score 2):

This is not available at the moment, but scheduled to release in about a week. Client TLS version will be logged into Azure Monitor for each request.

Comment: Thanks @vitaliy, Please update the variable name which is expecting to release

Comment: Is it available now @vitaliy?